# How to get rid of the glitch that occurs right after pressing the back button?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

A strange glitch happens when I press the back button.

The glitch happens during the transition from the actual View Controller to

the previous view controller.

A portion of another view controller appears for a brief moment between the

search bar and the first cell, and then it disappear.

(The black rectangle in the screen shots)

here are some screen shots and a link to a side project where I recreated

the problem.

Link to the project : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ak5mckhrysychlr/AACQd2Mwh5RxklmD1dv738h1a?dl=0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `opaque` navigation bar in some view controllers and `translucent` in some,that's y it's causing the issue,Change the navigation controller to `Translucent`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your `UINavigationController` to `Translucent` and this issue will be fixed.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Comment: I think you meant :  

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

Comment: Yes, in swift it meant that

Comment: Does the glitch disappear if I set all the navigationBars.translucent to false ?